# Macbook wont open ports

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to allow my phone to access a locally hosted website on my Macbook Pro as I develop it! its running 127.0.0.1 on port 5000 locally in a tango environment (i've been told that the 127.0.0.1 doesnt matter), and the IP that was given to me by my wireless router is 192.168.1.172. From what I've been told, I should be able to access the site from my phone on the same wireless network by going to 192.168.1.172:5000, however safari can never find the server! A quick port scan on my computer also shows that port 5000 isn't even open. How could I open this port so that I can access the site running on my computer?? Thanks so much for your help! Running the latest version of Mavericks.

Comment: you have to forward the port on the router your device.  Have you done this because it sounds like you have not.  Although you need to make sure your on the phone your actually connected to the same network as the macbook otherwise you won't be able to connect to the macbook no matter what you do.

Comment: So youre saying I need to port forward port 5000 on the router to the IP address in order to get that to work?

Comment: Yes;  If OS X has a firewall clearly you need to also allow the service/application.  Specifics are non existence.

Comment: Note that services running on 127.0.0.1 (as shown in netstat) are only accessible to the local host. Each application makes its own decision on what interface/ip to bind to and to what remote clients it respond to, so you will likely need to configure your development environment to allow remote connections, by binding to your lan ip address (192.168.1.172). *Nix systems use localhost-only services to facilitate communications between processes, which should never be visible to any other computer. Adjust your webserver config and then check netstat to make sure its listing on the lan ip.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to allow my phone to access a locally hosted website on 
>   my Macbook Pro as I develop it!

Ok. so we have at least two different devices here.

> it is running 127.0.0.1 on port 5000 locally in a tango environment
>   (i've been told that the 127.0.0.1 doesnt matter)

You were told incorrectly or perhaps with insufficient detail.
It does not matter it you use 127.0.0.1:5000 or 192.168.1.172:5000 **when you connect from your macbook**.

It does matter when you try to connect from the phone.  127.1 is *local** host.  For the phone that means  the phone itself. For the macbook it means the macbook itself.  Trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:5000 from the phone will try to access something on the phone, not the webserver on your macbook.

> From what I've been told, I should be able to access the site from
>   my phone on the same wireless network by going to 192.168.1.172:5000

If you also host it on 192.168.1.172:5000, then yes.  But you will need to tell the webserver which IPs to listen to. A very sane default would be to bind to localhost only (so only to 127.1:5000 or ::1 5000).  Unless you changed that in the configuration then there is nothing listening on that IP:port pair.

> A quick port scan on my computer also shows that port 5000 isn't even open. How could I open this port so that I can access the site running on my computer?

Go to your webserver software and bind it to 192.168.1.172:5000

Answer (score 0):

In communications, 127.0.0.1 is *the self*: contacting 127.0.0.1:5000 then means contacting your own pc on port 5000. If you do that from a second pc, it will try to contact itself, not the first pc. If, from the first pc, you replace 127.0.0.1, you will get the same effect, because the first pc is trying to contact itself on port 5000.

But now, if you are trying to contact your first pc's address on port 5000 from the second pc, that is not a call to itself anyy longer, and no service will be available to reply to you.

This is a security measure: so long as your Web server is not secure, it is not exposed to the world at large. You will have to learn how to make it available, at some point in the future.

So what you need to do at this development stage to make it accessible from the outside is to set up port forwarding on the first pc, telling it to forward all requests on IP_Address_of_Web_server:5000 to 127.0.0.1:5000.

You can do it in a temporary way, which is character with the security measure discussed above. Suppose the IP address of the Web server is 192.168.1.10, then these two commands

```
  mkfifo mypipe
  nc -l 5000 0<backpipe | nc localhost 5000 1>backpipe
```

forwards port 5000 from you IP adddress to *the self*. It should work now.